# How can I add a URL param after a link is clicked in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, vuejs2

I have heading links on my sidebar that scrollspy on my main content and of course takes me to the referenced heading in the main content when I click on them. I have data coming from a JSON file and I would like to add the headings to the current url when they're clicked.

Let's say I have the headings(this is contained in my json object: `headings.text`):

1. Heading 1
2. Heading 2
3. Heading 4

When the user clicks on **Heading 1**, I want my current URL `www.something.com` to change to `www.something.com/Heading1` and likewise for the other headings.

How can I achieve this in Vue?

This is what I have so far.

```
   <b-list-group-item :href="`#heading-${headingHash(headings.text)}`"> <--Heading reference.
              <span>
                <b>{{ index + 1 }}.</b> {{ headings.text }} <-- Heading itself.
              </span>
   </b-list-group-item>
```

Would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/). Namely, you can define a click event function and use [Vue Router's programmatic navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) to navigate to the route you specify.

```
<template>
  <b-list-group-item
    @click="handle(headings.text)"
    :href="`#heading-${headingHash(headings.text)}`"
  >
    <span>
      <b>{{ index + 1 }}.</b> {{ headings.text }}
    </span>
  </b-list-group-item>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    handle(heading) {
      this.$router.push({
        path: `Heading${heading}`
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the url to change based on a `href` attribute, you need to use an `a` tag.

Otherwise, you can do it programmatically. So, instead of adding `href` to `b-list-group-item` to could add a click event that would trigger a function:

```
<b-list-group-item @click"changeUrl(headings.text)">
```

And your method could be something like:

```
methods: {
    changeUrl(text) {
      window.location.href = `#heading-${this.headingHash(text)}`;
    }
}
```